# iCloud Apple ID uses old defunct email

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

After updating my iPod I'm asked to enter the password for the iCloud account, which has an Apple ID which uses an older email which no longer exists. I don't remember the old password.

Is there a way to update to my current Apple ID? I don't have access to the old email for verification.

If it's not possible I could live without it as I don't really use iCloud.

Comment: Does it specifically say it needs your login information for iCloud? Usually this type of message on upgrade would be in relation to trying to sync purchases (whether free or not) made with the old Apple ID. See also [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250791/250837#250837).

Answer (score 1):

AppleID is tied to purchases though. Are you using a NEW AppleID for the iPod? If so, use THAT login for iCloud. If not, just create a new ID with an email account you currently use. You'll lose access to purchases from the old ID, and any documents saved in the cloud though.